# Sort simple array with a simple condition (Snippet Included)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort the cars by `model` and `month` and it works well.
But I have an average month `00` which I want to be the last record of each model instead of the first.

I have no idea how to achieve this. I have created a snippet. Any help please?

```js
let cars = [{
    model: 'Ford',
    month: '12'
  }, {
    model: 'Ford',
    month: '03'
  }, {
    model: 'Ford',
    month: '01'
  }, {
    model: 'Ford',
    month: '00'
  },
  {
    model: 'Ford',
    month: '05'
  },
  {
    model: 'Fiat',
    month: '05'
  },
  {
    model: 'Fiat',
    month: '01'
  },
  {
    model: 'Fiat',
    month: '00'
  }
];

console.log(`Unsorted cars: ${JSON.stringify(cars)}`);

const sorted = cars.sort((a, b) => a.model.localeCompare(b.model) || a.month.localeCompare(b.month));

console.log(`Sorted cars: ${JSON.stringify(sorted)}`);
```

Got:

[**{"model":"Fiat","month":"00"}**,{"model":"Fiat","month":"01"},{"model":"Fiat","month":"05"},**{"model":"Ford","month":"00"}**,{"model":"Ford","month":"01"},{"model":"Ford","month":"03"},{"model":"Ford","month":"05"},{"model":"Ford","month":"12"}]

**Expected:**

[{"model":"Fiat","month":"01"},{"model":"Fiat","month":"05"}, **{"model":"Fiat","month":"00"}**,{"model":"Ford","month":"01"},{"model":"Ford","month":"03"},{"model":"Ford","month":"05"},{"model":"Ford","month":"12"}, **{"model":"Ford","month":"00"}**]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could special-case the `00` month in your sort comparator function:

```js
let cars = [
  { model: 'Ford', month: '12' },
  { model: 'Ford', month: '03' }, 
  { model: 'Ford', month: '01' },
  { model: 'Ford', month: '00' },
  { model: 'Ford', month: '05' },
  { model: 'Fiat', month: '05' },
  { model: 'Fiat', month: '01' },
  { model: 'Fiat', month: '00' }
];

console.log(`Unsorted cars: ${JSON.stringify(cars)}`);

const sorted = cars.sort((a, b) =>
  a.model.localeCompare(b.model) ||
  (a.month == '00' ? 1 : (b.month == '00' ? -1 : a.month.localeCompare(b.month)))
);

console.log(`Sorted cars: ${JSON.stringify(sorted)}`);

// alternate solution without nested ternary operator
const sorted2 = cars.sort((a, b) =>
  a.model.localeCompare(b.model) ||
  a.month == '00' ||
  (b.month == '00' ? -1 : a.month.localeCompare(b.month))
);

console.log(`Sorted cars: ${JSON.stringify(sorted2)}`);
```

Comment: Got a warning: `Extract this nested ternary operation into an independent statement.sonarlint(javascript:S3358)`

Comment: @asfafafags See my edit for the `sorted2` function, that might resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

There are actually 12 months in a year. (I know right)

You can *safely* convert the month `'00'` to `'13'` and keep your sorting as-is

Eventually convert back `'13'` to `'00'` once sorted

This is not the best solution concerning the performance, but it's easy to set up and maintain :

```js
let cars = [{
    model: 'Ford',
    month: '12'
  }, {
    model: 'Ford',
    month: '03'
  }, {
    model: 'Ford',
    month: '01'
  }, {
    model: 'Ford',
    month: '00'
  },
  {
    model: 'Ford',
    month: '05'
  },
  {
    model: 'Fiat',
    month: '05'
  },
  {
    model: 'Fiat',
    month: '01'
  },
  {
    model: 'Fiat',
    month: '00'
  }
];

console.log(`Unsorted cars: ${JSON.stringify(cars)}`);

// replace the '00'

const ZeroFixed = cars.map(elem => { if (elem.month === '00') elem.month = '13'; return elem });

const sorted = ZeroFixed.sort((a, b) => a.model.localeCompare(b.model) || a.month.localeCompare(b.month));

// replace back the '13'

const SortedZeroFixed = sorted.map(elem => { if (elem.month === '13') elem.month = '00'; return elem });

console.log(`Sorted cars: ${JSON.stringify(SortedZeroFixed)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, the focus is on the sort compare function. You have the model and month check nailed. The challenging check is to rank "00" on the bottom. I have a number of versions of this:

- (a.month === '00') - (b.month === '00')
- (parseInt(a.month) === 0) - (parseInt(b.month) === 0)
- !Number(a.month) - !Number(b.month)

Conversely, if you wanted a pattern, say, "13", to rank higher above normal sorting, you negate the rule such as:

- (a.month !== '13') - (b.month !== '13')

When the logic is non-trivial I like to expand by repeated calculations of `cmp` as I work out the logic:

```js
(a, b) => {
  let cmp = a.model.localeCompare(b.model);   // model check
  if (cmp !== 0) return cmp;
  cmp = !Number(a.month) - !Number(b.month);  // "00" check
  if (cmp !== 0) return cmp;
  cmp =  Number(a.month) -  Number(b.month);  // month check
  return cmp;
}
```

I usually prefer it in that form to iron out the bugs, if you want to shorten it, I do a final refactor/rewrite condensing the solution:

```js
(a, b) =>    a.model.localeCompare(b.model)         // model check
          || !Number(a.month) - !Number(b.month)    // "00" check
          ||  Number(a.month) -  Number(b.month)    // month check
```

```js
const cars = [
  { model: 'Ford', month: '12' },
  { model: 'Ford', month: '03' }, 
  { model: 'Ford', month: '01' },
  { model: 'Ford', month: '00' },
  { model: 'Ford', month: '05' },
  { model: 'Fiat', month: '05' },
  { model: 'Fiat', month: '01' },
  { model: 'Fiat', month: '00' }
];

const sorted = cars.sort((a, b) => 
      a.model.localeCompare(b.model)
  || !Number(a.month) - !Number(b.month)
  ||  Number(a.month) -  Number(b.month)
);

console.log(`Sorted cars: \n${JSON.stringify(sorted)
                            .replace(/},/g, "},\n")
                           }`);

// Sorted cars:
// [{"model":"Fiat","month":"01"},
// {"model":"Fiat","month":"05"},
// {"model":"Fiat","month":"00"},
// {"model":"Ford","month":"01"},
// {"model":"Ford","month":"03"},
// {"model":"Ford","month":"05"},
// {"model":"Ford","month":"12"},
// {"model":"Ford","month":"00"}]
```